# Neo4j: fastest way to find a node: by id function or index?

Tags: neo4j, database-performance

Is it faster find a node by id function

```
MATCH (i:Item) WHERE id(i) = 2345 RETURN i
```

or by a property indexed?

```
MATCH (i:Item { name: "Foo"}) RETURN i
```

Profiling these queries I saw

- id function: 2 total db hits
- index: 1 total db hits

Comment: Searching Indexes will always be faster than anything else but what is your Question?

Comment: Is it find by id() faster than find by indexed property?

Comment: Just keep in mind that `ID()` can be recycled, so if you store it as a reference somewhere else the reference might be orphaned

Comment: Thank you I know but this is not my case. Just in theory which is faster? I know for ex in orientdb the find by id is done in constant time

Comment: If you made the query `MATCH (i) WHERE id(i) = 2345 RETURN i` (i.e. drop the label on `(i:Item)` it would be a single db hit too. It has the effect of removing the **Filter** step after the **NodeByIdSeek** step.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Find by id is always faster, as it directly points to the node-record.